# Onde devo declarar uma variável de instância em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, orientação-a-objetos, classes, variáveis-de-instância

Estou com dúvida sobre a criação de variáveis de instância em uma classe/função construtora JavaScript. Já li em vários lugares que a declaração de uma variável de instância é feita dentro do corpo da classe como no exemplo abaixo:

```javascript
function Spam() {
    this.foo = "foo"
}
```

Mas percebi que também posso declarar a variável no `prototype` da classe como no exemplo abaixo:

```javascript
Spam.prototype.bar = "bar";
```

E no final acabo obtendo o mesmo resultado:

```javascript
var mySpam = new Spam();
mySpam.foo    // => "foo": declarado no corpo da classe
mySpam.bar    // => "bar": declarado no prototype da classe
```

Qual a diferença entre os dois métodos de declarar uma variável de instância?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`foo` é uma variável apenas do objeto que você instanciou, enquanto `bar` é do protótipo dos objetos `Spam` (todos objetos).

A diferença é que no primeiro caso cada objeto tem sua própria variável, enquanto no segundo todos objetos daquele protótipo dividem a mesma variável.

```js
var mySpam2 = new Spam();

console.log(mySpam.bar); // "bar"
console.log(mySpam2.bar); // "bar"

Spam.prototype.bar = "qux";

console.log(mySpam.bar); // "qux"
console.log(mySpam2.bar); // "qux"
```

Perceba que ao alterar o valor de `bar` do protótipo isso afetou o acesso daquela propriedade em todos objetos `Spam`. Com a propriedade `foo` o mesmo não é possível, já que ela é propriedade do objeto e não do protótipo.

---

**Cuidado para não esconder o protótipo *sem querer***

A forma correta de alterar o valor do protótipo é como fiz no exemplo:

```
Spam.prototype.bar = "qux";
```

Perceba que estamos alterando explicitamente o protótipo. Cuidado que o seguinte, ao contrário do que pode parecer, **não** é equivalente:

```
mySpam2.bar = "baz";
```

Nesse caso **não alteramos o protótipo**, nos criamos uma nova propriedade apenas no objeto `mySpam2` cujo nome é o mesmo do utilizado no protótipo ("*escondendo*" a do protótipo nesse objeto).

Comment: Existe algum problema em se "esconder o protótipo"? Pelo que eu saiba, o princípio por trás da herança prototípica (em oposição à herança clássica) é justamente pegar um objeto existente, bem caracterizado, e afirmar "esse outro objeto se parece com aquele, as diferenças são x, y e z". (embora reconheça que na prática isso nem sempre é usado desse jeito)

Comment: @mgibsonbr, não, problema nenhum ([duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) é pra isso mesmo). Só frisei na resposta pois, para quem vem de outra linguagem (ex: static em Java ou C#), pode não ser tão óbvia a diferença.

Comment: Só esclarecendo caso alguém se confunda, em `mySpam2.bar = "baz";` o que será escondido não é o protótipo inteiro do objeto, mas somente a propriedade `bar`.

Answer (score 4):

A diferença é que a variável declarada no `prototype` é **compartilhada** entre todas as instâncias da classe. Se ela possuir um valor simples, isso não tem importância, mas se ela for uma variável complexa (uma lista, ou um objeto) então modificar seus componentes terá efeitos colaterais nos demais objetos da classe:

```js
function Spam() {
    this.a = 10;
    this.b = [1,2,3];
}
Spam.prototype.c = 10;
Spam.prototype.d = [1,2,3];
Spam.prototype.print = function() {
    console.log(JSON.stringify({a:this.a, b:this.b, c:this.c, d:this.d}));
}

var s1 = new Spam();
var s2 = new Spam();

s1.print();
s2.print();

s1.a = 20;
s1.b[1] = 4;
s1.c = 20;
s1.d[1] = 4;

s1.print();
s2.print();
```

Resultado:

```
{"a":10,"b":[1,2,3],"c":10,"d":[1,2,3]}
{"a":10,"b":[1,2,3],"c":10,"d":[1,2,3]}

{"a":20,"b":[1,4,3],"c":20,"d":[1,4,3]}
{"a":10,"b":[1,2,3],"c":10,"d":[1,4,3]}
```

Repare que quando você fez `s1.c = 20` ele **não** atribuiu `Spam.prototype.c`, e sim `s1.c`, por isso não houve efeito colateral. Mas quando você **leu** `s1.d` e em seguida modificou um de seus componentes (o segundo índice), então você acabou por alterar o objeto compartilhado.

De modo que - respondendo sua pergunta - o local correto de se atribuir qualquer variável de instância **mutável** é dentro do corpo da classe (construtor).