# Ao atribuir um atributo a uma função, é como se tivesse criando uma variável dentro dessa função?

Tags: javascript

Estou estudando *JavaScript* e, pelo que entendi, ao atribuir um atributo a uma função, é como se tivesse criando uma variável dentro dessa função, é isso? 
Por exemplo:

Função original:

```
function copaMundo() {}
```

Atribuindo uma propriedade e um atributo a função:

```
copaMundo.pais = "Rússia";
```

Séria esse o resultado final:?

```
function copaMundo() {
    var pais = "Rússia";
}
```

Comment: [A resposta para essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1871/onde-devo-declarar-uma-vari%C3%A1vel-de-inst%C3%A2ncia-em-javascript?rq=1) não responde sua dúvida?

Answer (score 1):

Não sei onde leste essa ideia mas não é bem isso, repara no exemplo:

```js
function copaMundoA() {
  console.log(1, typeof pais, copaMundoA.pais); // undefined Ruússia
}
copaMundoA.pais = "Rússia";
copaMundoA();

/****************************/

function copaMundoB() {
  var pais = "Rússia";
  console.log(2, typeof pais, pais); // string Rússia
}
copaMundoB.pais = "Rússia";
copaMundoB();
```

Propriedades atribuídas a uma função não ficam disponíveis "globalmente" no escopo da função. Podes aceder às mesmas se a função tiver nome via `fn.prop` como no exemplo.

Variáveis declaradas dentro da função ficam fechadas nesse escopo e portanto não acessíveis. Se quiseres ter variáveis de escopo privado podes usar uma IIFE e criar assim uma memória privada da função:

```js
var copaMundoA = (function() {
  var pais = 'Rússia';
  return function() {
    console.log(1, pais); // Ruússia
  }
})();

copaMundoA();

console.log(2, typeof pais); // undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Não, é diferente.. no seu exemplo, a variável declarada dentro da *function* (`var pais`) no último código não pode ser acessada fora da *function*, é local à function apenas, veja o exemplo:

```js
var func = function() { 
   var sobrenome = "da Silva"; 
   this.idade = 20;
};

func.nome = "João";

// acessível 
console.log(func.nome);  
// não acessível
console.log(func.sobrenome);
// não acessível
console.log(func.idade);
```

Comment: No caso, é como se ele "adicionasse" uma variável dentro da função, mas é um tipo de variável global, séria isso? a última duvida é a seguinte: funções anônimas são funções que não possuem nome, mas quando vc atribui uma função a uma variável, tecnicamente ela passa ter um nome, ou estou enganado? por exemplo: no exemplo dado por vc, vc atribuiu uma função a variável "func", isso não faz com que a função deixe de ser anônima?

Comment: Sim, é mais ou menos isso, a função é tratada com se fosse um objeto, e você adicionou um atributo nele. Sim é uma função anônima, e quando você atribui a uma variável, que é a partir de onde a função pode ser executada já que ela não tem um nome, é chamado de expressão de função (*function expression*): https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function